# Improve picture quality

Tags: css, wordpress, image, size

I am working on a wordpress website and I found that the articles' pictures on the main page are of poor quality ; but the pictures I loaded in wordpress media are good ones.

In ...wp/content/upload, I saw that the template make copies of the pictures loaded : 1024x768 ; 150x150 ; 220x165 ; 300x225 ; 700x400 ; 768x576.
With firefox "examin object", I saw that the picture loaded is the 220x165 one. Is it possible to force selection of a better quality one ?

Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is paste the following code in your theme’s functions.php file or in a site-specific plugin.

```
add_filter('jpeg_quality', function($arg){return 100;});
```

When you set the value to 100, it means that WordPress compress the image at its highest quality.

Here's a good video about it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ToMjVp5sDf0